# QUnit fixtures not being restored every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I'm new to QUnit and I'm trying to figure out how `#qunit-fixtures` are restored. As I understand it, everything in that element is reset before a new test is run. However, I'm seeing (what is to me) something strange. In the below example, there's a `form` in the fixture which consists of just an `input` element and a `div` with the class `has-error`. So as I understand, before each test is run, these should be restored to their original state.
I've specified a `keypress` event handler for `$('input')` to just hide the `div` in the fixture.

I have two tests which do the exact same thing: trigger a `keypress` on the input and assert that error text is hidden.

What I see is that only one the first one passes. Could someone explain this behavior to me?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-1.18.0.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">
      <form> 
        <input name="text" />
        <div class="has-error">Error text</div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="qunit-1.18.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      QUnit.config.reorder = false;
      QUnit.test( "test 1", function ( assert ) {
        $('#qunit-fixture').find('input').trigger('keypress');
        assert.equal($('#qunit-fixture').find('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
      });

      QUnit.test( "test 2", function ( assert ) {
        $('#qunit-fixture').find('input').trigger('keypress');
        assert.equal($('#qunit-fixture').find('.has-error').is(':visible'), false);
      });

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#qunit-fixture').find('input').keypress(function() {
          $('#qunit-fixture').find('.has-error').hide();
        });
      });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The point of the test is to test the `keypress` event. Regardless of what QUnit code is acting on the fixture, since it is a *fixture*,  if the first test runs `$('#qunit-fixture').find('.has-error').hide();`, shouldn't this be undone before the second test is run?

Comment: It seems like an unlikely test scenario, to conduct tests on the fixture itself. Suggestion: try other more typical testing.

Comment: I see these as tests of the event handlers rather than of the fixtures...

Comment: By default QUnit will change the order of the tests. To preserver order do this QUnit.config.reorder = false; So in your case it's always the 2nd test that's RUN that fails. To get this question fully answered you may want to explain precisely why you're doing this test because it does seem odd...to perform a test on part of the fixture, not knowing what other qunit code may be acting on it.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. So now I get why the failing test was alternating between the two. I've edited the question to clarify that I'm testing the event handler. Maybe I just don't understand what a fixture's supposed to be, but I thought it's something that's restored to its original state before each test is run.

Comment: The fixture is there for QUnit to use only, it's not meant to be touched by our tests.

Comment: But even QUnit's own intro [example](http://qunitjs.com/intro/) involves touching what's in `$('#qunit-fixture')`. If the fixture isn't meant to be touched, what exactly is it mean for?

Comment: I checked that out, was not aware. "By putting it in the #qunit-fixture element, we don’t have to worry about DOM changes from one test affecting other tests, because QUnit will automatically reset the markup after each test."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think QUnit removes the element you added in the fixture before it runs each test. So the "keypress" event handler added on document ready is removed by the time the 2nd test starts. It will work if you add the event handler at the start of each test, or on document ready like this:

```
$("body").on("keypress","input",function( event ) {
        $('.has-error').hide();
});
```

QUnit may not remove it for the first test which explains why it works the first time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just realized that!